# Array shape unable to get from the loop Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, append

Was trying to build an artificial data set of two arrays .
X of shape (100,2) - Income and age to appear in two columns.
y of shape (100,1)

When appending with loop i am getting X of only (200,1).

There is no error but the intention to feed the model is to generate np array of 100x2

Appreciate your support.

```
from scipy.stats import norm 
import random
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval
from ast import literal_eval
from pandas import DataFrame


# Function for N points in k clusters to generate artificial data
def create_clustered_data(N,k):
    random.seed(10)
    points_per_cluster=float(N)/k
    X=np.array([])
    y=np.array([])
    for i in range(k):
        income_centroid=np.random.uniform(20000,200000)
        age_centroid=np.random.uniform(20,70)
        for j in range(int(points_per_cluster)):
             X=np.append(X,[np.random.normal(income_centroid,10000),np.random.normal(age_centroid,2)])
             y=np.append(y,i) 
             X=np.array(X)
             y=np.array(y)
    return X,y

(X,y)=create_clustered_data(100,5) # using the function to create two arrays

print(X[0:4]) # getting the income and age appending together in single dimension
X.shape # I need to get the shape as (100,2) instead of (200,1) currently being achieved
X.ndim # I need to get this as 2 instead of 1 currently being achieved
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your np.array to standard python list and use the `+=` operator to append the values to the list. You will also need to enclose your record in square brackets `[]`, see `[[np.random.normal(income_centroid, 10000), np.random.normal(age_centroid,2)]]`

```py
# Function for N points in k clusters to generate artificial data
def create_clustered_data(N,k):
    random.seed(10)
    points_per_cluster=float(N)/k
    X=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(k):
        income_centroid=np.random.uniform(20000,200000)
        age_centroid=np.random.uniform(20,70)
        for j in range(int(points_per_cluster)):
             X += [[np.random.normal(income_centroid, 10000), np.random.normal(age_centroid,2)]]
             y += [i]
    return X, y

(X,y) = create_clustered_data(100,5)
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

and after you convert `X = np.array(X)`, the
`X.shape` will return `(100, 2)`

Comment: Thank you. I get the dimensions as required for the output X of the function.But i need to have it in array format to feed to the  scatter plot (currently getting as list)and the svm.SVC Model .These two statements inside the loop is throwing error (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple)                                                     
     X=np.array(X)
     y=np.array(y)

Comment: Thank you. I get the dimensions as required for the output X of the function.But i need to have it in array format to feed to the scatter plot (currently getting as list)and the svm.SVC Model .These two statements inside the loop is throwing error (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple) X=np.array(X) y=np.array(y)

Comment: ```plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=y.astype(np.float))
plt.show() ```                                                                                                           
     ERROR MESSAGE                        
 ```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-82b40bdc9ac4> in <module>
      1 plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
      2 
----> 3 plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=y.astype(np.float))
      4 plt.show()

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

<Figure size 576x432 with 0 Axes>```

Comment: what do you mean? I tried `plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=y.astype(np.float))` outside the function (after converting `X` and `y` to numpy) and it worked.

Comment: Hi, I am feeding the output from the function to scatter plot for which i need an array and further i need the array to feed the SVM model

Comment: have you tried converting  `X=np.array(X)` and `y=np.array(y)` after calling your `create_clustered_data` function?

Comment: yes. Please see the code block below of the user defined function (sorry the code is not appearing in a structured way to view)                                                             . ```for j in range(int(points_per_cluster)):
             X += [[np.random.normal(income_centroid, 10000), np.random.normal(age_centroid,2)]]
             y += [i]
            X=np.array(X)
            y=np.array(y)
            
    return X,                                                                       y (X,y)=create_clustered_data(100,5)
```

Comment: you are converting it inside the function. Try converting it outside the function, see my edited answer.